# What is the meaning of 14.8.2 paragraphs 3 and 4 in the C++ Standard?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm struggling to understand this rule, specially the sentences in bold below (my emphasis):

Consider the comment #2 in the snippet below: what does it mean to say that the function type is `f(int)`, but `t` is `const`?

> **`§14.8.2/3`**:
>
> > After this substitution is performed, the function parameter type adjustments described in 8.3.5 are performed.
> >     [ Example: A parameter type of “`void ()(const int, int[5])`” becomes “`void(*)(int,int*)`”.
> >     —end example ] [ Note: **A top-level qualifier in a function parameter declaration does not affect the function
> >     type but still affects the type of the function parameter variable within the function. —end note** ] [ Example:
> >
> > ```c++
> > template <class T> void f(T t);
> > template <class X> void g(const X x);
> > template <class Z> void h(Z, Z*);
> > int main() {
> >     // #1: function type is f(int), t is non const
> >     f<int>(1);
> >     // #2: function type is f(int), t is const
> >     f<const int>(1);
> >     // #3: function type is g(int), x is const
> >     g<int>(1);
> >     // #4: function type is g(int), x is const
> >     g<const int>(1);
> >     // #5: function type is h(int, const int*)
> >     h<const int>(1,0);
> > ```
> >
> > }
> >
> > —end example ]

> **`§14.8.2/4`**:
>
> > [ Note: **`f<int>(1)` and `f<const int>(1)` call distinct functions even
> >     though both of the functions called have the same function type.** —end
> >     note ]

Comment: Related: [Inconsistent use of const qualifier between declaration and definition](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20659598/1708801)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider:

```
template <class T> void f(T t) { t = 5; }
```

`f<int>` is well-formed, but `f<const int>` is not, because it attempts to assign to a `const` variable.

See: [Use of 'const' for function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117293/use-of-const-for-function-parameters)

Comment: Not particularly; the first sentence of 14.8.2.1p3 is more relevant.

Answer (score 6):

If you had two functions

```
void f(int x);
void g(const int x);
```

then both functions would have the same function type. This type is denoted `void(int)`, and a function pointer of type `void (*)(int)` would be able to point to either function.

This is what is meant when we say that the top-level `const`-qualifiers on the parameters to a function do not affect the *type of the function*.

However, this does not mean that the `const` is meaningless. In the definition of `f`, you would be able to modify `x`, but in the definition of `g`, you would not be able to modify `x`, since `x` has type `const int`.

Comment: @Mao毛泽东 No, not really. If you're curious what that bullet point means, post another question.