# Why does the declaration `void(*pf)(int) = bar;` fires the `static_assert` in the snippet below?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

This is a continuation of [my prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24617413/3694387). Note that the declaration `void (*pf)(int) = bar;` fires the `static_assert`. I don't understand why. Note also that if I replace `bar`by `bar<const int>` in this declaration the code compiles.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
void bar(T t)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, const int>::value, "Error!");
    std::cout << t << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    //  static_assert doesn't fire because T==const int
    bar<const int>(1);

    //  But here static_assert fires because T==int (see the error message). Why is this?
    //  If I replace `bar` by `bar<const int>` below the code compiles.

    void(*pf)(int) = bar;
    pf(1000);
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d23432b0dd91e2c3)

Comment: The compiler is deducing that `T` = `int` based on the function pointer signature provided. Changing `void(*pf)(int)` to `void(*pf)(const int)` doesn't fix it though, presumably because the const qualifier is dropped somewhere along the chain. Someone here can probably say exactly where.

Comment: Why did you expect `T` be `const int` in `void(*pf)(int) = bar` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 I wasn't expecting anything. I was just trying to verify that the type of the function `bar` instantiated by the the expression `bar<const int>(1);` was `bar(int)` from my prior question. But then I realized that the compiler is instantiating another function `bar<int>` with the declaration `void(*pf)(int) = bar;`. And this I can't understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior is quite straightforward. `T` is being deduced as `int` from the function pointer type below, hence the `static_assert` fails.

```
void(*pf)(int) = bar; // [T = int]
```

> if I replace `bar` by `bar<const int>` in this declaration the code compiles

That's because you've now explicitly specified that `T` is `const int`, and it's no longer being deduced as `int`.

```
void(*pf)(int) = bar<const int>; // [T = const int]
```

You're still allowed to create a function pointer of type `void(*)(int)` to the function `void(const int)` because top level `const`s are not part of the function signature.

Adding `const` to the function pointer type doesn't help because of the same reason, the top level `const` in the function argument type is discarded before `T` is deduced, and it results in the same behavior as the first example.

```
void(*pf)(const int) = bar;  // [T = int]
```

Comment: So how come `void(*pf)(const int) = bar` fails?

Comment: @MattPhillips Same reason, the top level `const` is discarded before `T` is deduced.

Comment: "Same reason"?  Ah I see you've edited your question to put in what dlf answered.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out (if that's really correct), that the type of `void(*pf)(const int)` really *is* `void(*)(int)`.

Comment: `T is being deduced as int from the function pointer type below, hence the static_assert fails.` Can you provide a quote from the Standard supporting this?

Comment: @MattPhillips By "same reason" I meant this sentence from *my* answer - *because top level consts are not part of the function signature* - which was the last sentence before I added the final paragraph to address your comment. And I didn't *edit anything in* from dlf's answer, everything but the last paragraph, aside from a couple of grammatical improvements, were present in the very first revision I submitted.

Comment: @ChairmanMao [dcl.fct]/5 "The type of a function is determined using the following rules. [...] After producing the list of parameter type, any top-lvel *cv-qualifiers* modifying the parameter type are deleted when forming the function type." This applies as well to function pointers. For the deduction, see [temp.deduct.funcaddr]

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is deducing that `T` = `int` based on the function pointer signature provided. Changing `void(*pf)(int)` to `void(*pf)(const int)` doesn't fix it though, because cv qualifiers are dropped during type deduction (and, as dyp pointed out in the comments, when determining the type of a function). § 14.8.2.1/3 of the C++11 draft ("Deducing template arguments from a function call"):

> If P is a cv-qualified type, the top level cv-qualifiers of P’s type
>   are ignored for type deduction

To fix this, explicitly indicate the type you want:

`void(*pf)(const int) = bar<const int>;`

Comment: I do think it rather has to do with `void(*)(const int)` being *the same type as* `void(*)(int)`.

Comment: Yes; I assume that's why the rules say to ignore cv qualifiers here.

Comment: No, what I mean is that `std::is_same<void(*)(const int), void(*)(int)>::value == true` even though there is no deduction involved.

Comment: The deduction for `void(*pf)(int) = bar;` happens according to [temp.deduct.funcaddr], which specifies it via `template<class T> void deduce( void(*)(T) );` called with an argument of type `void(*)(const int)`. Since deduction here happens according to [temp.deduct.type], you cannot just drop the `const`. Consider `template<class T> struct foo{}; template<class T> void deduce( foo<T> );` called with an argument of type `foo<int const>`.